# Relative % between two measures in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm in late stages of a project where I extracted around 200k comments from a community and ran them past a sentiment analysis cognitive engine. I have sentiment data with 4 values over time. The values are `mixed`, `neutral,` positive`and`negative`. As amateur as I am in PowerBI I was able to get this rudimentary graph:

[image]

I've grouped the data by date, and selected months as the grouping within. So each point of data is a month. What I would really like is to understand how to plot a relative value for the `positive` and `negative` data points. I guess for each timeframe I would like to plot the % of positive and negative between each other. For example:

- First time frame, total positive = 10, total negative = 10 **=>** 50% for each
- Second time frame, total positive = 30, total negative = 10 **=>** 80% for positive, 20% for negative.

Could anyone let me know how I change my PowerBI configurations to get to this relative % instead of total over time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use these 2 measures for that:

```
% negative = 
VAR sentiments = SUM('Comments'[positive]) + SUM('Comments'[negative])
RETURN
    DIVIDE(
        SUM('Comments'[negative]), 
        sentiments
    )
```

```
% positive = 
VAR sentiments = SUM('Comments'[positive]) + SUM('Comments'[negative])
RETURN
    DIVIDE(
        SUM('Comments'[positive]), 
        sentiments
    )
```

Comment: Thank you Peter. I'm a total Noob on PBI. Can you link me to a doc where I can add/edit these in?

Comment: Hover over your table name "Comments", click on the ellipsis (...) and from the dropdown select "New measure".  You can also go to the Modelling tab and find a "New measures" Icon there.

Comment: You're the best Peter, right answer for you. thanks for your time.